# C# Hotchocolate mutation without input param does not work

Tags: c#, hotchocolate

I have the following mutation type

```
[MutationType]
public static class FooMutation
{
    public static async Task<Guid> CreateFoo(CreateFooCommand request, [FromServices] ICommandBus commandBus) => await commandBus.Send(request);
}
```

I have the following command (which does not work)

```
public record CreateFooCommand : ICommand<Guid>;
```

And I have the following handler

```
public class CreateFooCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateFooCommand, Guid>
{

    public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateFooCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var foo = Domain.Foo.Create(userId);
        
        return foo.Id;
    }
}
```

If I do something like the following in the Command, It will works fine

```
public record CreateFooCommand(string? IDoNotNeedAnyParam) : ICommand<Guid>;
```

But I do not need any param, and when I remove that param I get:

1. InputObject `CreateFooCommandInput` has no fields declared. (GraphQL.Foo.Mapping.RequestTypes.CreateFooInput)

Which should be totally fine by GraphQl standards.

The poor hotchocolate documentation does not tell anything about mutation types without parameters, so I think this should work, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HotChocolate supports mutations without arguments. But your mutation has argument! `request` is treated as mutation argument. That's why HotChocolate tries to expose `CreateFooCommand` class as `CreateFooCommandInput` GraphQL type in the output schema. And you get the exception because GraphQL spec doesn't support types without any field.

To fix that just, simply create the command manually:

```cs
public static async Task<Guid> CreateFoo([FromServices] ICommandBus commandBus)
    => await commandBus.Send(new CreateFooCommand());
```